# Popup issue showing Access Point and the address in 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. a pop-up appearing and disappears quickly, but this is related to the Access Point and the address http://nmcheck.gnome.org/check_network_status.txt. How to stop this pop-up issue permanently.